# Android Jetpack is not part of AOSP platform APIs

Tags: android, android-source, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Google recommends using Android jetpack library (e.g Workmanager for background task) to improve performance and efficiency. But why jetpack library is not packed with android platform library, rather it is available as support library. Also it is not a part of AOSP. So if someone wants to use it do he need to copy code and change gradle build support to Android.mk build. And then only he can use library with AOSP code?

Comment: But why jetpack library is not packed with an android platform library, rather it is available as a support library? I guess google left this decision to developers itself. The things which are done by jetpack can also be done via other methods. Google want to give choice to developers. moving jetpack to platform is basically will make the platform heavier even for those who won't use it.

Comment: "The things which are done by jetpack can also be done via other methods.". Agree. Actually this question came to mind when I saw google strongly recommending to use WorkManager in their Android S documents. Also I did not see system app using those libraries. Though user app can easily add it through gradle dependency. Looks like it is recommended for user application development mostly. If system application wants to use the library they can copy and compile within AOSP workspace.

Comment: So, I guess we cannot use data binding too in platform apps. This means that if I already developed some application by making use of data binding I must rework them if I want to build using .mk/.bp files.. this is very unconfortable and limiting for who usually works with databinding .. is there any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not part of the Android team, so this is basically a guess based on what I read.

If, for example, WorkManager were part of the platform instead of a library, when Google wanted to update it with new functionalities, they would need to ship it with a new version of Android. And your users would have to update their device OS in order for your app to be able to use those new functionalities. Historically, Android device manufacturer are not very good at releasing updates to their devices.

Since it's an independent library, every app has their preferred version of WorkManager built into the APK and you can update your app whenever you want. You also don't have to worry about whether your user is on version X or Y of the OS. All users will get same experience.

There are downsides to that, of course (like increasing APK size). But I think it's easier to handle the Gradle dependencies than to have conditions throughout your app like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   // use feature available only in Android O and above
} else {
   // do something else on earlier Android
}
```